# Missing country in a layout

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, geography

***Which country fills in the yellow cell?***

[image]

---

*A cell becomes empty when no country meets the criterion that the country in a non-empty cell meets.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The country in yellow is

> Turkey, or as they would insist I refer to it as, Türkiye

Why?

> The middle cell represents 0°N 0°E (aka Null Island), and each other cell represents a step of 10 degrees north/south and east/west from an adjacent cell. Thus, the yellow cell is at 40°N 40°E, which is located in Turkey.

Comment: What about the empty cells?

Comment: @ArturoVialArqueros I didn't do any research, but there may be places in an ocean and not on any land in the grid.